# Allowing web access to an Amazon EC2 Windows Server 2008 instance running Tomcat+application?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

The instance I choose was the following:

```
Basic 64-bit Microsoft Windows Server 2008 (AMI Id: ami-d9e40db0)
Microsoft Windows 2008 R1 SP2 Datacenter edition and 64-bit architecture.
```

I have installed Tomcat + an application and AM able to see the website when I access the local IP thru IE (in the EC2 instance).

However, when I try accessing it as:

```
* the assigned Elastic IP
* the ec2-999-999-999-999.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

from the EC2 instance itself or from outside, it doesn't work. IE says:
    Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

I've tried:

```
* disabling the Firewall -> no luck
* waiting for a bit -> no luck
```

I can't ping the machine assigned Elastic IP either.

The allowed connections (as seen in Amazon's Management Console) is as:

```
Connection Method  Protocol From Port     To Port   Source (IP or group)
SSH              tcp               22          22   0.0.0.0/0
RDP              tcp             3389        3389   0.0.0.0/0
DNS                 tcp            53          53   0.0.0.0/0
DNS                 udp            53          53   0.0.0.0/0
HTTP                tcp            80          80   0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out... I wasn't disabling *ALL* of the Windows Firewalls!!

There are 3 in Windows Server 2008

Domain Profile

Private Profile

Public Profile

Disabling in each made it work... of course, at production time I will set these appropriately...

Comment: Can you please provide the details how did you do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be disabling your firewall. This would compromise the security of your app and server VM. Instead modify the windows server inbound firewall rules to allow incoming traffic on specific ports.

I encountered a similar issue with windows server 2012. I addition to having the correct security group settings, you also have to manually modify the firewall rules on the windows server.

I have documented both security group settings and firewall rules here:
http://abhirampal.com/2015/08/04/firewall-config-for-java-web-app-hosted-on-aws-ec2-windows-2012-server/

Note: its likely that your settings for your prod environment would be even more strict than the ones listed at the webpage available at the link.